# Can one integrate Microsofts Web Speech API in Java?

Tags: javascript, java, speech

Microsoft's free Web Speech API offers one functionality I would like to use. It's however written in JS and working in the Chrome/Edge browsers.

Is there a way to make it work/callable from Java? Mainly I want to pass `myString` from Java to JavaScript and execute the following code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
     speechSynthesis.speak(new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(myString));
  </script>
```

I can imagine to make it work via a servlet. If possible though I would prefer to strictly decouple it from the browser or a server.

Another way would be to let an Engine execute the code, e.g. Rhino. However this requires it at least to already know about all dependencies first + maybe other stuff.

I would be happy about any constructive comment, idea or answer.

Comment: did you find a solution for this?